# Как выбрать регуляркой дробный номер дома?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста выбрать из строки адреса номер дома. Я умею выбрать номер дома, который состоит из цифры(12), из цифры с Буквой корпуса(12Б), но не умею выбрирать дробный номер дома(6/2).

```
// const addr = 'Россия, Москва, улица Гагарина';
// const addr = 'Россия, Москва, улица Гагарина, д. 11A';
// const addr = 'Россия, Москва, улица Гагарина, д. 11';
const addr = 'Россия, Москва, улица Гагарина, д. 6/2';
const homeNum = addr.matc
```

h(/\d+[а-яА-Яa-zA-Z]?$/);

console.log(homeNum[0])

[LIVE DEMO здесь.](https://jsfiddle.net/nrtgpyw8/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте альтернативы:

```js
const addrs = ['Россия, Москва, улица Гагарина', 'Россия, Москва, улица Гагарина, д. 11A', 'Россия, Москва, улица Гагарина, д. 11', 'Россия, Москва, улица Гагарина, д. 6/2'];
const rx = /(?:^|[^а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z])д\.\s*(\d+(?:[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z]|\/\d+)?)$/;
for (var addr of addrs) {
  console.log(addr);
  const homeNum = addr.match(rx);
  if (homeNum) {
    console.log(homeNum[1]);
  } else {
    console.log("Нет совпадения.");
  }
}
```

**Подробности**

- `(?:^|[^а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z])` - начало строки или любой символ кроме буквы
- `д\.` - подстрока `д.`
- `\s*` - 0 и более пробельных символов
- `(\d+(?:[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z]|\/\d+)?)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1:

  - `\d+` - 1 и более цифр
  - `(?:[а-яА-Яa-zA-Z]|\/\d+)?` - опциональная незахватывающая подмаска:
  - `[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z]` - 1 буква
  - `|` - или
  - `\/\d+` - `/` и затем 1 или более цифр
- `$` - конец строки.